# Exclude rows by identifying a sequence using subset()

Tags: r

I am trying to exclude a series of rows from a dataset by using the subset() command by identifying a sequence of numbers in the "Rec" column that I want to remove. My attempts to use : and > within subset have failed, for example:

```
dataset<-subset(dataset,Rec !1812:1843) #here I'd like to exclude all rows with values of 1812:1843 for Rec in the dataset
```

or

```
dataset<-subset(dataset,Rec !>1812) #here I'd like to exclude all rows with Rec>1812
```

Can someone show me how to use the <> and : operators in this way? Can it be done with subset()?

Comment: `here I'd like to exclude all rows with Rec>1812` why not `Rec<=1812` then?

Comment: You need `!=` instead of `!`, or `<=` instead of `!>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For inclusion/exclusion based on membership in a list in general, you can use the `%in%` operator:

```
dataset <- subset(dataset, !(Rec %in% 1812:1843))
```

Comment: This works only if `Rec` takes only integer values, which is not specified. `Rec < 1812 | Rec > 1843` would work for non-integer values (and also be at least slightly computationally faster, especially for large ranges)